# How do I replace a String[ ] with a ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, jsoup, picasso

I'm trying to populate my gridview with images using picasso. I'm using jsoup to collect the image links and placing them into a ArrayList. I have something wrong with my ImageAdapter cause none of my images load when I start the app. My log shows the links being collected so that works. Any help will be appreciated. I'm posting the entire code for the Activity.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity
  {GridView grid;
String url="http://dstreet.site/";
String link,title,src;
ArrayList list= new ArrayList();



   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Scrapper();
    grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, list));


    }


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    ArrayList list;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    Context c;
     int mCount;

    ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList list) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        c = context;

        mCount = list.size();
        this.list=list;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return true; 
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View 
    convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.img, parent, 
       false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            assert view != null;

            holder.imageView = (ImageView) 
      view.findViewById(R.id.image);


            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        Picasso.get()
            .load(list.get(position))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .fit()
            .into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception p1)

    {holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    // TODO: Implement this method
                }


                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

   holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }


            });

        return view;
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;

}
public void Scrapper()
{
    Content content= new Content();
    content.execute();
}

public class Content extends 
   AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void[] p1)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method

        try
        {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            // Identify Table Class "worldpopulation"
            for (Element table : 
     doc.select("div[class=poster]")) {

                Elements imgSrc = 
   table.select("img[src]");
                // Get only src from img src
                src = imgSrc.attr("src");
                list.add(src);
            }







            Log.d("image links",list.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {e.printStackTrace();


        }
        return null;


    }

}}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And `java` tag at least

Comment: Well that's just it I don't know what to try. The code works using that String[] IMAGE_URLS = Constants.IMAGES; but I want to use the info from my ArrayList list. So picasso .load IMAGE_URLS [position ] isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace String[] with ArrayList then you need to use ArrayList.get(position) instead of IMAGE_URLS [position].

Comment: So I updated my code in its entirety.When I run the app no images load. I must be doing something wrong at the start of the Imageadapter like adding the ArrayList list wrong. Will you give it a look?

Comment: What is the type of ArrayList, String or any object? If it is Object ArrayList then ArrayList.get(position).imagename else if it is String arraylist please debug and check whether arraylist empty or not.

Comment: It is a String Array and my log shows my list is populated with urls. I know how to attach a static string to the adapter but I've never used a arraylist like this before so I'm unsure how to attach the array. Please look back at the code to see if i have the attachment wrong

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not iterating over the elements after you queried the table for images:

```
for (Element table : doc.select("div[class=poster]")) {

    Elements imgSrc = table.select("img[src]");
    src = imgSrc.attr("src");
    list.add(src);

}
```

Something like this should do it:

```
doc.select("div[class=poster]")               // get list of div
   .stream()                                  // for each div
   .map(table -> table.select("img[src]"))    // find all images
   .flatmap(Elements::stream)                 // collapse images into 1 list
   .map(imgSrc -> imgSrc.attr("src"))         // for each image
   .forEach(list::add);                       // add to Collection
```